# How to work on internationalization of Pyramid forms?

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, chameleon, deform

I have been looking online for localization of *error messages* and **labels** of pyramid forms but so far without any luck. I have worked on both pyramid_simpleform and pyramid_deform. Has anyone worked on something similiar. The docs are not much of help.

The example given on  [this page](http://deformdemo.repoze.org/i18n/) does not work for me.

I also tried the docs of [pyramid_deform](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/i18n.html) and [pyramid_simpleform](http://packages.python.org/pyramid_simpleform/#localization-and-state).

I do not care which form library I use. I want something that has straightforward support for localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what has worked for me.

```
   from pyramid.i18n import get_locale_name
   from pyramid_simpleform import Form,State
   from formencode import api as formencode_api
   def includeme(config):
     config.scan(__name__)
     config.add_route('login', '/login')

   @view_config(route_name='login',renderer='website/login.mak')
   def login(request):

     formencode_api.set_stdtranslation(languages=[get_locale_name(request)])

     form = Form(request,
            defaults=dict(request.params),
            schema=MySchema,
            state=State()                
            )
     form.state._ = ''
```

Comment: I was so frustrated that I gave up and started working with wtforms. I will try the solution, thanks a lot man

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. I also had trouble trying to find a solution for this since the docs don't help that much. Please confirm if it worked for you.